# How is it possible to check out for some particular elements in a list by some and/or conditions in one if statement

Tags: python, if-statement

I have the list of tuples

```
a=[('H40T','H04H'), ('Z40A','H04T'), ('M90K','H04B'), ('H40H','H04B'), ('H40A','A04B'), ('A40T','Q04Q'), ('H40T','H04H'), ('Z40A','L04M'), ('A03C','H04T'), ('H40T','H04B'), ('H40A','A04B'), ('H40T','Q04C')]
```

and I am going to just keep the tuples that they have at least one of the elements `desire=['H04B','H04T','H04H']`

I tried to used this code, but it did not remove all the tuples without the mentioned elements.

```
for counter in a:
    if ('H04B' not in counter and 'H04T' not in counter and 'H04H' not in counter):
         a.remove(counter)
```

The problem is for the tuples have none of them. Also, I tried `any()` to find the unwanted elements.

```
for counter in a:
    if any(x in counter for x in desire):
       a.remove(counter)
```

Comment: The main problem with your approach is that you are removing elements from the list while iterating through it. You should create a new list of the filtered results as written in the answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a list-comp with a set-intersection and keep tuples where there's at least some intersection with your desired values, eg:

```
desired = {'H04B', 'H04T', 'H04H'} # using a set instead of list...
b = [el for el in a if desired.intersection(el)]
```

Gives you:

```
[('H40T', 'H04H'),
 ('Z40A', 'H04T'),
 ('M90K', 'H04B'),
 ('H40H', 'H04B'),
 ('H40T', 'H04H'),
 ('A03C', 'H04T'),
 ('H40T', 'H04B')]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a list comprehension and `any` to do the filtering

```
>>> desired = ['H04B','H04T','H04H']
>>> res = [t for t in a if any(e in t for e in desired)]
>>> 
>>> print (res)
[('H40T', 'H04H'), ('Z40A', 'H04T'), ('M90K', 'H04B'), ('H40H', 'H04B'), ('H40T', 'H04H'), ('A03C', 'H04T'), ('H40T', 'H04B')]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
a=[('H40T','H04H'), ('Z40A','H04T'), ('M90K','H04B'), ('H40H','H04B'), ('H40A','A04B'), ('A40T','Q04Q'), ('H40T','H04H'), ('Z40A','L04M'), ('A03C','H04T'), ('H40T','H04B'), ('H40A','A04B'), ('H40T','Q04C')]
desire=['H04B','H04T','H04H']

remove_lst=[]
for idx,counter in enumerate(b):
    if all([d not in counter for d in desire]):
            remove_lst.append(counter)
   #         print('removed',counter)
new_list = [el for el in b if el not in remove_lst]
print(len(new_list))
new_list
```

For example:

```
b=[1,2,3,3,4,5]
for idx,el in enumerate(b):
   print(idx,el)
   if el==3:
       b.remove(el)
```

The output will be:

```
0 1
1 2
2 3
3 4
4 5
```

Cause when you iterate through a list and remove an element it will skip next one cause it iterates through the updated one with removed elements;

One way might be to work with a copy of the list or remove elements afterward like the above code or sets are a nice way to solve it.

```
b=[1,2,3,3,4,5]
c=b.copy()
for el in c:
   print(el)
   if el==3:
       b.remove(el)
```